# What happens if an own-goal is scored during a delayed penalty shot (ice hockey)?

Tags: rules, officiating, ice-hockey, nhl, penalty-shot

The NHL rules are contradictory in this circumstance, and do not specify what course of action is to be taken. I know this is a little contrived, but is not a long-shot to occur.

Relevant rules, emphasis mine:

> 24.1 Penalty Shot –
>   **A penalty shot is designed to restore a scoring
>   opportunity** which was lost as a result of a foul being committed by the
>   offending team, based on the parameters set out in these rules.
>
> 24.6
>   Should two penalty shots be awarded to the same team at the
>   same stoppage of play (two separate fouls), **only one goal can be scored or awarded at a single stoppage of play. Should the first
>   penalty shot result in a goal, the second shot would not be taken but
>   the appropriate penalty would be assessed and served for the
>   infraction committed**.
>
> 24.7 Timing -
>   If the foul upon which the penalty shot is based occurs
>   during actual playing time, **the penalty shot shall be awarded and
>   taken immediately in the usual manner notwithstanding any delay
>   occasioned by a slow whistle by the Referee to allow play to continue
>   until the attacking side has lost possession of the puck to the
>   defending side, which delay results in the expiry of the regular playing
>   time in any period.**
>
> 78.5 (xi)
>   **During the delayed calling of a penalty, the offending team cannot
>   score unless the non-offending team shoots the puck into their own
>   net.** This shall mean that a deflection off an offending player or any
>   physical action by an offending player that may cause the puck to
>   enter the non-offending team’s goal, shall not be considered a legal
>   goal. Play shall be stopped before the puck enters the net (whenever
>   possible) and the signaled penalty assessed to the offending team.
>
> 78.6
>   **Only one goal can be awarded at any stoppage of play**.
>
> Source: http://www.nhl.com/nhl/en/v3/ext/rules/2015-2016-Interactive-rulebook.pdf

**Rule 24.1** details what a penalty shot is: it replaces a lost scoring opportunity.

**Rule 24.7** tells us that the penalty shot officially occurs at the stoppage of play, **not** when the infraction occurred. This means that when the attacking side is able to maintain control of the puck after the infraction, and they pull their goalie, and manage to score on themselves (explicitly allowed as a goal for the offending team in **rule 78.5 (xi)**), the penalty shot would occur at the exact same stoppage of play as the offending team's goal.

However, this is a problem. We know that only one goal can be awarded at any stoppage of play, as detailed in both **Rules 78.6 and 24.6**.

So what happens? Does

(a) the offending team's goal count, and the penalty shot is not taken,

(b) the offending team's goal not count, and the penalty shot is awarded,

(c) the offending team's goal count based on the outcome of the penalty shot (i.e., if the penalty shot is good, the goal is disallowed, but if the penalty shot fails, the goal is allowed),

(d) the offending team's goal count, and instead of the penalty shot, a penalty is assessed and served by the offending team,

or (e), both goals are awarded, despite the rules saying only one can be awarded at any stoppage of play.

Scenarios (a) and (e) seem very unlikely. Scenario (b) seems pretty likely, though there is nothing in the rules that should disallow the offending team's goal. Scenario (c) seems to be the outcome most supported by the rules, as the scoring opportunity the penalty shot restores occurred before the offending team's goal. Lastly, Scenario (d) seems supported by a very liberal interpretation of **Rule 24.6**.

Any help or more rules that could provide clarification or shed some more light is greatly appreciated. I've thought about this for a few years and I desperately want scenario (c) to be true, though I suspect it's (b) or (d).

Answer (score 4):

(e) is what would happen.  There's no reason this would be interpreted any differently than the rules regarding a power play; in particular:

24.6 indicates that `only one goal can be scored or awarded at a single stoppage of play`, but the own-goal was scored *prior* to a stoppage of play (it was the *cause* of the stoppage of play; the play had continued due to the delayed penalty shot until the puck is touched by the offending side *or a goal is scored*.

78.6 discusses video review, and disallows the second goal because play *should* have stopped after the first goal or disallowed goal, so it attempts to "reset" to the situation prior to the incorrect call on the part of the officials.  It has nothing to do with a delayed penalty or delayed penalty shot, unless a delayed penalty shot time also involves a goal that is missed by the officials.

We know that (e) is what would happen for a regular power play, because it has happened before; [Patrick Kane scored an own goal against Edmonton on January 12, 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v6_oXtwAYE) [(box score)](http://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201401120CHI.html).  The goal is credited to Boyd Gordon (SH) (EN), but of course that's because he was the last person to touch the puck prior to the delayed penalty.

Comment: The own-goal isn't scored *prior* to the stoppage of play, it occurred in conjunction with the stoppage of play, and is awarded *at* the stoppage of play. Also, the situation you provided is a different scenario. I know that the goal counts when it occurs during a normal penalty (ie not a penalty shot) but that's because there isn't another goal it's "competing" with. The scenario you linked seems to support (d), anyway

Comment: (d) is what happened when a normal penalty was assessed; (e) is what would happen if a penalty shot was called for.  I don't think you're going to get a different answer from this, unless Brendan Shanahan or someone happens across it; this is not something they're going to cover in detail given I don't think it's ever happened nor is likely to (I think the Kaner was the first ever with a minor penalty).  But I don't think they'd do anything else; there's no other reasonable thing.

Comment: And further, I think you're wrong about the stoppage.  The goal scored during live play.  The stoppage occurs once the goal is scored.